# \mathit spacing with \mathnormal font

Tags: math-mode

I noticed that while `\mathit{AHfi}` sets the spaces and ligatures correctly (like `\operatorname`), the letters look narrower than the ones produced by `\mathnormal{AHfi}`. Is there a way to typeset a multi-letter math operator in the mathnormal font?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you should use `\mathit` or `\mathrm`  (or higher level constructs like `\DeclareMathOperator`) for multi-letter identifiers. The math italic (`\mathnormal`) font is specifically designed so that characters have larger sidebearings to separate them so that `abc` looks like an implied product of `a` times `b` times `c` rather than the identifier `abc`. This is a property of the font itself and not something under the control of TeX.

Comment: Thank you. I'm asking this because I think I've seen multi-letter identifiers typeset in this way, e.g., on page 20 of the book "Principles of Model Checking" by Baier and Katoen (a link to a pdf of the book can be easily found by googling), in the definition of transition systems, the set "Act" is typeset in the mathnormal font.

Comment: well there's nothing to stop someone using `$Act$` or even `$A\mkern-1mu ct$` as a single identifier if they wish, it is just that the font is not designed for that use.

Comment: @warakawa I'm afraid that a book dealing substantially with math that doesn't use `amsmath` for its typesetting can't be regarded as a model for typography. The usage of `eqnarray` on page 25 is revealing. `;-)` Also the usage of `$Act$` or `$\mathit{Act}` is not consistent: either can be found.