# How should I typeset the physical dimensions of quantities?

Tags: fonts, typography, best-practices

As an example: The Newton's Law gives

```
F=ma      vs.      dim F=MLT^{-2}
```

My question is: Should I typeset the "MLT" in `\mathit` shape?

You can contrast

```
\[\mathit{LT}\mathit{LT}\mathit{LT}\mathit{LT}\]
\[\mathit{L}\mathit{T}\mathit{L}\mathit{T}\mathit{L}\mathit{T}\mathit{L}\mathit{T}\]
```

the latter is more close together. Is there some tricks on using `\mathit` shape?

Or I should choose the `\mathrm` family, or even just the default math font?

Comment: If `M`, `L` and `T` are variables, treat them just like you would `m` and `a`; as-is.

Comment: As far as I know, dimensional quantities (I don't know if this is the correct word in English) as `M`, `L`, `T` in physics **have** to be typeset in upright shape. So you'd better use `\mathrm` for them.

Comment: And anyway `\mathit` is more or less the same font used by default in math mode. See this thread for more details: [\mathit spacing with \mathnormal font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101154/27635)

Comment: "Quantity symbols are always written in an italic font, and symbols for dimensions in sans-serif roman capitals" ([page 105] (http://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si_brochure_8.pdf)).

Comment: I would use upright, but possibly `\mathsf`, to set them apart, since they are neither text, nor variables.

Comment: Use the `siunitx` package?

Answer (score 13):

Both, the SI-Brochure nr. 8 (section 1.3, p. 105) and DIN EN ISO 80000-1:2012-10 (chapter 5, p. 19) use upright capital and sans-serif letters for this.

> Quantity symbols are always written in an italic font, and symbols for
>   dimensions in sans-serif roman capitals - SI-Brochure

Therefore you should write dimensions of quantities like this:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[%
    ,math-style=ISO
    ,bold-style=ISO
    ,sans-style=italic
    ]{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\[\dim Q = \mathsfup{L}^\alpha \mathsfup{M}^\beta \mathsfup{T}^\gamma \mathsfup{I}^\delta \mathup{\Theta}^\varepsilon \mathsfup{N}^\zeta \mathsfup{J}^\eta\]
\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image]

Unfortunately, there is no sans-serif font for medium-weight Greek letters in the range of uni-code characters. But if you normally use italic capital Greeks in your document (`math-style=ISO`), it will be distinguishable.

---

Three other remarks on your OP:

- Your two examples for `$\mathit{LT}$` and `$\mathit{L}\mathit{T}$` should (and do) look the same.
- The default math font normally yields the same as `\mathit{...}`.
- Before I edited your question, you wrote: "[F]=MLT^{-2}". Please note that `[Q]` means "the unit of Q". `{Q}` would signify "the value of Q" and for your case, it should be `dim Q`. `$Q = \{Q\}\cdot[Q] \wedge \dim Q = \mathsfup{L}^\alpha \dots$`.

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[X]=\mathsfup{L}`? The operator `\dim` has a different meaning.

Comment: You refer to the dimension of a vector space? I am not into that anymore, seems to be the same operator. But ISO and SI both use it in this place, too. `[X]` is the unit of X.

Comment: @egreg any idea on how to get an `\mathsfup{\Theta}`? The more I look at it, the less I like the serifs here.

Comment: For information on the different conventions for the symbol `[X]`, see [Square bracket notation for dimensions and units: usage and conventions](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/77690/8563) at Physics.SE.

Comment: I have a question regarding the code snippet provided by @LaRiFaRi.

I get an error message: LaTeX Error: Unknown option `sans-style=italic' for package `unicode-math'

Do you know why?